# Encoding error while trying to read and write in html file with Java

Tags: java, html, encoding

I'm trying to read some text from an html file, modify it in a specific way and write the result in a new html file. But the problem is that the text is not written in English and as a result some characters are replaced with  black and white "?" marks. In my html file, I have  `< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. What am I doing wrong? Maybe not the right Readers and Writers?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputFile.html"));
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line);
}
String result = doSomeChanges(sb);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputFile.html")); 
out.write(result); 
out.close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Maybe not the right Readers and
>   Writers?

Exactly. `FileReader` and `FileWriter` are garbage; forget that they exist. They implicitly use the platform default encoding and do not allow you to override this default.

Instead, use this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("inputFile.html"), "UTF-8"));

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("outputFile.html"), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileReader` and `FileWriter` use the platform default encoding, which isn't what you want here. (I've always viewed this as a fatal flaw in these APIs.)

Instead, use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` respectively. This allows you to explicitly set the encoding - which in this case should be UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You use BufferedReader, which ignores the html-structure of the file. Thats why `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` has no effect.

Try this one:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("zzz"), "utf8")));
```

Comment: No, it's got nothing to do with BufferedReader itself. It's the use of FileReader which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier you can also use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) project which has read and write methods for Files and Strings which consider encoding.